# Is string value type or reference type

Tags: .net, asp.net

Is `string` a reference type or a value type? Can anyone give a corresponding description?

Comment: A closure vote as "Subjective and Argumentative"? What's subjective about this question, seriously?

Comment: How is this "not a real question", for that matter?

Answer (score 8):

`string` is an Immutable Reference Type. Below is a short example:

```
// All of these point to the same string in the heap
string hello = "Hello World!"; // creates string
string hello2 = "Hello World!"; // uses the previous string from the intern pool
string hello3 = hello2;
```

If you're looking for more information, check out Jon Skeet's post:

[C# in Depth: Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`System.String` in the .net framework is a reference type, a very good explanation is that by Jon Skeet: [C# in Depth: Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx). The key points from his article are:

- It is a reference type
- It's immutable
- It can contain nulls
- It overloads the == operator

The last point is the one that makes `string` behave like a value type at times as you can write:

```
string s1 = "value";
string s2 = "value";
// result will be true.
bool result = (s1 == s2);
```

Comment: Actually that's an unfortunate example - string interning would make that true even without == overloading.

Comment: @Jon - I'd forgotten about that - cantcha tell it was nearly hometime! :S

Answer (score 0):

Check out the chapter [Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx) by our very own master, John Skeet, from his book 'C# in Depth'. It tells you all you need to know.